# sitting on a table with sifrei kodesh on it

Tags: halacha, books-generally, standing-sitting

Is there a halachik problem with sitting on a table or surface that has siddurim/chumashim on it? What about other sefarim? What about putting one's feet on a table that has such books on it?

Answer (score 5):

this article on the Topic says there is a basic consensus of Poskim that say you may not sit or put your feet on a place with seforim as printed seforim have the same or slightly lesser level of kedusha and most be shown respect as such.
[Source](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5762/bo.html#)

Answer (score 2):

A Jew is not supposed to sit on a table as a table is similar to a Mizbayach.

http://ravbaruch.com/AskTheRabbi.asp?QID=41

Comment: Gershon do you have a halakhic source for this?  I was fairly certain that this was just an Ashkenazi custom.

Comment: mekubal, that it is an Ashkenazi custom can also be called a source.

Comment: I was more wondering where the custom is recorded and by whom, and which communities rely upon it.

Comment: Gershon, that is a great source!  Thank you.

Comment: The source you linked to basically says the opposite of what you said in your answer (about sitting on tables in general), although he says that there might be some basis for those who want to avoid sitting on tables that are usually used for sefarim. In an [archived version of the original article](http://web.archive.org/web/20090326060210/http://afoksy.com/AskTheRabbi.asp?QID=180), R' Rubanowitz adds that it may be reasonable for a parent to tell a child not to climb on a (generic) table for derech eretz reasons, although the shulchan-as-mizbeiach idea would not be relevant.